# Regex for boolean logic

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to use a regex to validate a string. It should allow white spaces between a string and a booleaen operator like `(@string1    OR)`, but disallow white spaces in between strings like `(string  1)`. Other boolean logics allowed are:

```
(A AND B) AND (NOT C)
(A OR B) AND (NOT C)
(A AND B)
(A OR B)
(NOT C)
```

Examples of possible valid and invalid inputs are below.

Valid:

```
(@string1 OR @string2) AND ( NOT @string3)
(@string-1 AND @string.2) AND ( NOT @string_3)
(@string1 OR @string2 OR @string4) AND ( NOT @string3 AND NOT @string5)
(@string1    OR   @string2   OR    @string4)
(@string1 AND @string2 AND @string4)
( NOT @string1 AND NOT @string2 AND NOT @string4)
( NOT @string1 AND NOT @string2)
```

Invalid:

```
()
(string  1 OR @str ing2) AND ( NOT @tag3)
(@string 1 OR @tag 2) AND ( NOT @string 3)
(@string1  @string2) ( NOT @string3)
(@string1 OR @string12) AND (@string3)
(@string1 AND NOT @string2)
```

Is it better to parse the string and then have multiple regexes check for the absence of whitespaces, or can a regex be written to check the entire string?

Comment: These queries can have nested `(...)`, correct?

Comment: Also, what stops the user from having  :- NOT NOT, where the second NOT is a string?  I guess what I am asking is, how do you tell what is and is not a string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes that is correct.

Comment: @grail. They user might be able to do a Post using NOT NOT but they validation should catch that. Not sure if that answers your question

Comment: Not really.  How will the validation know the difference between NOT NOT as qualifier and string as opposed to NOT NOT string where 2 qualifiers have been used to turn the resulting value into a truth.  So you have not answered the second part of my previous question, which is, how do you tell what is and is not a string?

Comment: If nested `(...)` were not to be supported, you might have tried [this regex](http://rubular.com/r/B30UQJMfzq). But with those nested parenthesis you'd better go for a full-blown grammar parser.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov, thanks this REGEX works well when nested is not supported, and I think I will not support nesting for now. However, what changes would I have to make to the regex if I want to accept a string without parenthesis or without Boolean logic: eg (@test)

Comment: I believe this is an XY problem. You want a tokenizer or full blown grammar parser like @DmitryEgorov said. [Citrus](https://mjackson.me/citrus/index.html) and [TreeTop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) are two examples.

Comment: [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/get-started.html) is another grammar parser. These will not only validate your strings but tokenize and allow you to evaluate them.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of sophisticated validation would be best solved with a grammar parser.

Just to get you started, here is an (incomplete) solution in parslet. As you can see, you build up from primitives and construct more and more complicated structures.

```
require 'parslet'

class Boolean < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:space)  { match[" "].repeat(1) }
  rule(:space?) { space.maybe }

  rule(:lparen) { str("(") >> space? }
  rule(:rparen) { str(")") >> space? }

  rule(:and_operator) { str("AND") >> space? }
  rule(:or_operator) { str("OR") >> space? }
  rule(:not_operator) { str("NOT") >> space? }

  rule(:token) { str("@") >> match["a-z0-9"].repeat >> space? }

  # The primary rule deals with parentheses.
  rule(:primary) { lparen >> expression >> rparen | token }

  rule(:and_expression) { primary >> and_operator >> primary }
  rule(:or_expression) { primary >> or_operator >> primary }
  rule(:not_expression) { not_operator >> primary }

  rule(:expression) { or_expression | and_expression | not_expression | primary }

  root(:expression)
end
```

You can test a string with this little helper method:

```
def parse(str)
  exp = Boolean.new
  exp.parse(str)
  puts "Valid!"
rescue Parslet::ParseFailed => failure
  puts failure.parse_failure_cause.ascii_tree
end

parse("@string AND (@string2 OR @string3)")
#=> Valid!
parse("(string1 AND @string2)")
#=> Expected one of [OR_EXPRESSION, AND_EXPRESSION, NOT_EXPRESSION, PRIMARY] at line 1 char 1.
#   ...
#   - Failed to match sequence ('@' [a-z0-9]{0, } SPACE?) at line 1 char 2.
#      - Expected "@", but got "s" at line 1 char 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need recursion or loop, and a stack to parse that properly and regex alone will be very difficult albeit impossible to validate that.